# how to remove warning ".productAdapter" is never read locally?

Tags: android, warnings, adapter

I am very new in android Development. I am getting a warning when i build my project. waring is:

The field SavedSalesHistoryList.productAdapter is never read locally.

Can any one help me?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should mean that a private variable, `productAdapter` in your case, is not being used. You can safely delete it from the `SavedSalesHistoryList` class.

Answer (score 1):

It means you never actually used that item.  You can safely delete or comment it's declaration out.  You're wasting CPU cycles allocating memory to it and never using it, then letting it get garbage collected (if an object).  Granted, small things like this wont impact the performance of EVERY project, but it makes for cleaner code.